# Django - Performing a subquery on a subquery and then getting all associated fields

Tags: django

I have data in the following form:

```
collection_name | type       | manufacturer | description | image_url
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
beach           | bed        | company a    | nice bed    | 1.jpg
beach           | king bed   | company a    | nice bed    | 1.jpg
beach           | nightstand | company a    | nice ns     | 1.jpg
grass           | chest      | company a    | nice chest  | 2.jpg
apple           | chest      | company a    | nice chest  | 3.jpg
fiver           | chest      | company b    | good chest  | 4.jpg
```

and models like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    collection_name = models.TextField(null='true',blank='true')
    type = models.TextField(null='true',blank='true')
    manufacturer = models.TextField(null='true',blank='true')
    description = models.TextField(null='true',blank='true')
    image_url = models.TextField(null='true',blank='true')
```

What am I trying to do in my app at the moment is:

- Link to a product by id (using the hidden pk id field),
- Then for that id get the collection name
- Get a list of products with that collection name
- Get a list of distinct image_urls from the set of products with a certain collection name *
- for each image_url in the new set, get all records that have the same image_url

The reason I want to do this, is as you can see in the above sample data, different products sometimes reuse the same image (some images show multiple products in one image). I want to show each image only once, while being able to show all products associated with a given image (of which there could be multiple).

I've been thinking to do something like the following based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55068511/9919430) answer, which I think follows the logic given above, but I'm not sure it is the correct approach.

```
collectionname = product.objects.filter(id=id).values('collection_name').distinct()
images = product.objects.filter(collection_name__in=collectionname).values("image_url").distinct()
results = []
for img in images:
    pbis = product.objects.filter(collection_name__in=collectionname, image_url=img['image_url'])
    obj = {"image": img['image_url'], "items":[{"attr":pbi.attr, ...} for pbi in pbis]}
    results.append(obj)
```

What are the obvious errors in my approach here, and is there a better, cleaner way to do this? In case it is relevant, the backend is postgres.

What I would like to be able to do in the template is something like:

```
{% for instance in image_url %}
{{ collection_name }} Collection:
<img src="{{ instance }}">
Product type: {{ instance.type }}
Product Description: {{ instance.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which should output something like:

For 1.jpg:

```
Beach Collection
<img src="1.jpg">
Product type: bed
Product Description: nice bed
Product type: king bed
Product Description: nice bed
Product type: nightstand
Product Description: nice ns
```

For 2.jpg:

```
Grass Collection
<img src="2.jpg">
Product type: chest
Product Description: nice chest
```

For 3.jpg:

```
Apple Collection
<img src="3.jpg">
Product type: chest
Product Description: nice chest
```

For 4.jpg:

```
Fiver Collection
<img src="4.jpg">
Product type: chest
Product Description: good chest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a couple of extra models would make it easier to work with your content: `Collection` and `Image`. For your Image model, I'd recommend using Django's `ImageField`, which is more fully featured than just saving the URL as text. To use ImageField, you need to install `Pillow`, which is a current maintained fork of the Python Image Library (`PIL`). Do this with `pip install Pillow` on the command line. An ImageField has a built-in attribute `url`, so you can still access the URL of your image easily (see template below). Then your new models.py can be:

```
# models.py
class Image(models.Model):
    source = models.ImageField(upload_to='my_media_path')

class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    feature_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name='collections', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name='products', on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 
    # or ManyToManyField if a product has several images
```

Then you can get the other products that are in the same image as your selected product:

```
bucket = Product.objects.get(pk=1)
bucket.image.products.all()
<Product: Bucket>
<Product: Spade>
```

And for your templates - which organise content by collection mainly:

```
# query
collections = Collection.objects.all()

# template.html
{% for collection in collections %}
    <h1>{{ collection.name }}</h1>
    <img src="{{ collection.feature_image.source.url }}">
    {% for product in collection.products.all %}

        <p>{{ product.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ product.description }}</p>

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT:

With no time to implement the above approach, the approach you mentioned will work fine. You can change one line in the view code to keep it simpler:

```
...
obj = {"image": img['image_url'], "items": pbis}
```

And then when you pass the `results` dict to the template context:

```
{% for collection in results %}
    {{ collection.items.0.collection_name }} Collection:
    <img src="{{ collection.image }}">
    {% for item in collection.items %}
        <p>Product type: {{ item.type }}</p>
        <p>Product Description: {{ item.description }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is interesting and I am still looking it over. I should note that my situation is not typical, and while I make the models with django, I import the data directly into postgres, as it comes in bulk via an API and needs to be modified a lot before it can be used. I actually have an image_path and image_url field, with the image_path field being a FileField type and is used with easy_thumbnails package.

Comment: I am worried to change the model definitions like this since I think it will make importing data as I need to harder, and everything works at the moment, except for being able to query in the way I need/want to.

Comment: I see what you mean. Your approach of creating the equivalent of a collection model and queryset in memory feels awkward to me though if your display is based around collections. How about if you left the Product model and image settings as they are, and just added a Collection model to your Django project (and Postgres)? It wouldn't affect any existing data import process. And when you import the Product data, it could get-or-create a Collection based on the product's collection name and add the product to that collection - using a signal or a custom save method, for example.

Comment: If you'd rather not do that, there is nothing wrong with the approach you mention in your question. The view code is fine and your template snippet would need only minor adjustments to work as intended.

Comment: I agree my current method is clunky, but I've been working under pressure and with limited knowledge to get this working at all. I had plans for "Version 2" to do as you suggest, to have a collection model and create it somehow when inserting data, but it's something I need/want to learn how to do and won't be able to do before I need to have this current project ready.

Comment: I know how it goes. I've edited my answer with the minimal changes you'd need to make to get your above approach working (haven't tested it though).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! I was going to add that if you wanted I could provide my more complete models if you wanted to expand your answer, as I agree doing it in memory is clunky, and using a model is better, but I think I will leave it  until I have more time..which isn't long, I plan on addressing it in April. At the moment I am attempting to use my more clunky solution, and modified the line in my view as you suggested, but this gives a key error on image_url and I can't figure out why this is. Anything I can provide to give more info?

Comment: I am guessing it is because my line `collectionname = product.objects.filter(id=id).values('collection_name').distinct()` is not returning anything, because the code all looks correct?

Comment: Hmm, should return empty, not a key error. I tried it at this end and works OK. Print the output of each line and see if you can debug. Make sure "Product" is capitalised not lower case as it was in your snippet, and imported correctly. I can look at rest of view code on chat if still an issue.

Comment: Hey birophilo, I got it working, thank you! I am still having images repeating when displaying and can't figure out why, if you would be willing today would you be able to take 5 mins to take a look? I'm hesitant to post a new question when it's likely a very simple thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189734/discussion-between-birophilo-and-jake-rankin).